# Geting value of variable using gdb on core dump file

Tags: debugging, gdb, binaryfiles, coredump

Can someone help me understand how to identify the value of a variable using gdb. I have a binary file and the core dump file (I don't have the original code). I'm trying to identify the value of a variable, so I tried `bt full` to generate the full backtrace. However, I keep getting `No symbol table found` afterwards. I've done a fair bit of googling so far and all I've found is that the binary file might have been optimized, so what I need to do is go back and re-compile without `-O`; however as I said before, I don't have the original file. The goal is to be able to find the value without it. If not using gdb, is there any other debugger software that could help me with this?

Some further comments:
I've tried going to the specific frame and using `info locals` and that also produces a `No symbol table found`. 
I've also tried using `print` and `info locals`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to identify the value of a variable

What *kind* of variable?

For a global, you can just `print a_global`.

> so I tried bt full to generate the full backtrace. However, I keep getting No symbol table found afterwards.

The "no symbol table" really just tells you that there is no debug info (which is required to print *parameter* values, and values of local variables).

> I don't have the original code

... and your binary was built without debug info.

In that case, you will have to resort to assembly-level debugging. You would need to understand the ABI and calling convention for your platform, disassemble the function you are interested in, and figure out where in memory (or in which register) the variable of interest results, then examine that memory (or register).